# Eclipse Plugin Version Mismatch Issue

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, version

We have been having an interesting issue with the Eclipse update when some of our users update our feature/plugin to the latest release. Please see screenshot attached.

We have observed that in some cases the feature updates (and shows in the about dialog) the correct version number but when we take a look at the plugin details some of the plugins show the correct version but some of them still show the older version numbers even when the latest jars are in the plugins folder. Does anyone know why this would happen and how can we avoid this. This behavior is not consistent in all installation but we have seen it happening in Eclipse 3.5.

Will appreciate any help.

[image: Version Mismatch]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that I can think of is that some of your plugins are not contained in your feature, but are dependent on plugins that are included in the feature.

Eg- Feature A v1.0.0.x contains Plugin 1 v1.0.0.x and plugin 1 depends on plugin 2 with no version constraints.

If you have A v1.0.0.x, 1 v1.0.0.x and 2 v1.0.0.x installed, and upgrade A to v1.1.0.x, 1 will be upgraded to v1.1.0.x, but 2 will be left unchanged.

So, the thing to check here is to make sure that when you install your product, all plugins that are installed are contained inside of a feature.  And, when you perform an update, all of the features are updated together.

Comment: Thanks for the response Andrew, I made sure that all the plugins needed are present in the feature. So when eclipse starts it should get the latest plugins.

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear. I checked that all the things mentioned were in order but it still did not fix the problem.

Comment: Odd...the next thing I'd check is the feature itself.  A feature will have hardcoded plugin versions.  So, if you look at the feature.xml of the feature from the update site, you should see the mismatched version numbers.  If that is the case, then it must be something with how you are generating the plugins themselves.

Comment: Andrew, Sorry for the late reply. I didn't get the notification for your comment. I checked the feature.xml and it has the correct version numbers. But the current installation does not show the problem. So I do not have a consistent way to reproduce the issue. It could be anything from a corrupted workspace to a problematic plugin release. I am still not sure how to fix this. But thanks for the suggestion I will make sure we check the feature.xml everytime before we push out a release.